# C# Pairing HTML Tags to check if they are properly balanced

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Thanks for the tip below

•   You need to go through the string one character at a time (for loop or while loop) When you hit a < you know you have hit a tag, so store the position of this character

•   Keep going (in a sub-loop, preferably) until you hit a >, that's your end marker

•   Now check the character immediately before the >. Is it /?

•   YES: Peek at the top of the stack. Is that string the same as the one between < and />?

If yes, pop that item and break out of the subloop (you found a match!).

If no, return false from the method - your work is done (the HTML is not valid).

•   NO: then push the whole string between < and > onto the stack and break out of this subloop, and continue the main loop.
As @seesharper suggested, turn the above into psuedocode then into C#.
Good luck on your journey learning to program!

Comment: Are you supposed to be able to support self-closing tags? E.g. `<br />`? Also, closing tags are formatted like `</Good>`, not `<Good/>`.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with tag balance. You need to write more-complex code that keeps track of entire tags.

Comment: This function matches opening < and closing > characters, it doesn't match tags. You need to *understand* code, not just copy it. Suggestion: write out how you would do this task manually, turn those instructions into pseudo-code, and finally into C#.

Comment: Hint: the code you have does help. Using a stack is  good way to go, but instead of matching < and >, match opening tags with closing tags.

Comment: You'll learn more by completing your assignment without using the code of others (within constraints, of course you have the entire .NET library available to you).  Using 3rd party code you don't understand is a recipe for disaster.  I sincerely wish you good luck as you endeavor to improve your programming skills!

Comment: Please leave the original question in place: the fact you've marked an answer means that people can see it easily, but you've just edited your question and replaced it with my answer so people can't easily see what the original question was.  Thanks for the check mark and I hope you enjoy your future programming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my analysis of the problem (I'm not going to give you the code solution to the problem, as others have pointed out this defeats the purpose of this sort of exercise).  I'm also not dealing with inconsistently formatted (but still valid) HTML and open-close tag special cases such as `<br />`, which are common in real HTML:

- You need to go through the string one character at a time (`for` loop
  or `while` loop) When you hit a `<` you know you have hit a tag, so
  store the position of this character
- Keep going (in a sub-loop, preferably) until you hit a `>`, that's
  your end marker
- Now check the character immediately before the `>`.  Is it `/`?
- YES: Peek at the top of the stack.  Is that string the same as the one between `<` and `/>`?

  - If yes, pop that item and break out of the subloop (you found a
    match!).
  - If no, return false from the method - your work is done
    (the HTML is not valid).
- NO: then push the whole string between `<` and `>` onto the stack and
  break out of this subloop, and continue the main loop.

As @seesharper suggested, turn the above into psuedocode then into C#.

Good luck on your journey learning to program!

Answer (score 3):

Your current code simply checks that "{open}" is complete, and that whatever the next tag is, is also complete, not that it is paired with its close tag.

You need to be operating with strings instead of characters.  You're going to read in "{open}" and "{/open}" and you need to operate on them.

Start by making a list of your use cases:

1. You start with a close tag - Work out how do identify it is a close tag, and then when you try to pop your empty stack you know it fails your check.
2. You start with an open tag - Work out how to identify it is an open tag, and then push it onto your stack.
3. You find a "complete tag" - one in this format "" - Work out how to identify this type of tag.  Do nothing with it, he does not need to be paired once identified correctly.
4. You encounter multiple open tags in succession.  push each onto the stack.
5. You encounter a close tag - determine if it is properly paired with the top element of the stack - pop and continue if they are properly paired - fail if they are not.
6. You encounter multiple close tags in succession.  Rinse and repeat 5 until tags do not match or you have an empty stack and an unmatched close.

You have a lot of good logic in your current code, but it needs to be expanded to properly perform the task assigned.

NOTE:  I have intentionally not provided code, but some logic to help you toward your solution because this is a homework assignment.  You will be working almost exclusively with 1) Reading a file.  2) Strings.  3) Stack.  Resources for syntax, properties, and methods of each are readily available should you need to look them up.

Also, I used the wrong braces because just tags weren't showing up and it was a quick edit.